# How does Keras choose the final model if validation data is given?

Tags: validation, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

The final training step may not have the lowest loss if the loss fluctuates.

**I want to know, if validation is given to training a model in Keras, how does Keras pick the final model?**

Does

1. Keras pick by choosing a **model with the lowest loss on validation data from the whole training process**?

Or

2. Keras pick the **final model from the final training step**, regardless if the final model gives the minimum loss on validation data?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, by default Keras return the final model from the final training step, regardless if the final model gives the minimum loss on validation data.

If you want to use a model with the lowest loss on validation data, you need to use the [ModelCheckpoint](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ModelCheckpoint) callback with parameter `save_best_only`. After training is done, you need to load saved model. It will be the best model in terms of loss on validation data.

```
save_best_model = ModelCheckpoint(best_model_path, monitor='val_loss', 
                                  save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=True)

# fit model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, 
              batch_size=64,
              epochs=35,
              validation_data=(X_val, y_val), 
              callbacks=[save_best_model])

# select the best model
model.load_weights(best_model_path)
```